# mv - how to escape backslash in file name?

Tags: bash, command-line

I copied a file to my Ubuntu vm with a backslash in the name, and I cannot figure out how to rename the file, e.g. `mv .\Dockerfile Dockerfile` -- the command line does not like that syntax for the filename but I'm not sure how to escape the `.\Dockerfile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
mv \\Dockerfile Dockerfile
```

Comment: thanks `mv .\\Dockerfile Dockerfile` worked, although tab completion kept wiping it out, probably my terminal's fault